# Stuck with reputations

Tags: discussion

Somehow I am stuck with "reputations" in [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).
Can't answer a question due to the lack of "reputation", neither put a comment, due to the lack of "reputation" and, - therefore, - won't gain any "reputation"...

How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *had* been temporarily and automatically blocked from answering due to a number of your posts picking up flags (I suspect you know the ones I'm talking about) and then being deleted.

The auto-block is there to stop people running around the site posting rubbish in the deepest nooks and crannies. It's not the most intelligent thing in the world but it's there for a good reason.

The block is now gone but I'd suggest you spent a little more time making your answers the best they could possibly be *before* you post them on the sites.

There are also other ways of earning reputation. Improving existing posts (improving formatting, improving the language, etc) is a good earner for people still learning Ubuntu. It's also a good way to learn things. But make sure you read the documentation on this before you head off and start editing things as if too many of your edits get rejected, you'll be blocked from that too.

Comment: Yeah it must be quite difficult for a bot to distinguish between a "troll" and a quick but useful answer. Sometimes users need quick answers to solve a problem without having to read a 50+ pages manual. Anyways, the "issue" seems to be solved now. Have a good day.

Comment: @mcantsin the flags come from real users.

Comment: Just once again: I cannot even upvote your helpful answer because of lack of "reputation" in here. - I have other business to do today than collecting tockens. So I will, - possibly, - come back another day...

Comment: and I myself cannot see such "flags"?

Comment: ... anyways. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @mcantsin upvotes just need 15 reputation and you already have that.

Comment: @Braiam yes, I have that now, but not 1 hour ago, so upvoted you now. ;) Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

See https://askubuntu.com/tour

It will explain it all. Specifically:

[image]